# Obtener el valor del toggle al momento de hacer clic

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, checkbox

espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, tengo toda la mañana intentando
recuperar el valor que se genera al utilizar un checkbox convertido con ayuda de bootstrap
a un botton toggle.

```html
<div class="online center-block" >
<label class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="mantenerRegistro" name="mantenerRegistro" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SÍ ACEPTO" data-off="NO ACEPTO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
<div id="console-event"></div>
</label>
</div>
```

los botones funcionan de maravilla, sin ningún inconveniente
Como puedo recuperar el valor del checkbox, ya lo intente utilizando este código de donde obtuve el otro sin éxito:

```js
<div id="console-event"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
      $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
    })
  })
</script> "Es como referencia ya que hay que cambiar algunas cosas".


Y pues no logro que obtenga el valor del checkbox que ha sido marcado.

Saludos
```

Comment: ¿Cuál elemento tiene el id `toggle-event`?

Comment: ¿No será `$('#mantenerRegistro')`?... [Ejemplo](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/KKraoPZ).

Comment: Si así es el '#mantenerRegistro' es el id del checkbox, pero no hace nada el script.  Por eso solicite apoyo para ver en que me equivoque desde el principio pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `input[type=checkbox]` tiene un el atributo `input.checked` donde se guarda el estado.

Además, tal como te han dicho en los comentarios, tu input es `#mantenerRegistro`

Ejemplo con javascript

```js
const toggle =  document.getElementById("mantenerRegistro");

toggle.addEventListener("input", () => document.getElementById("console-event").innerHTML= `Toggle: ${toggle.checked}`);
```

```html
<div class="online center-block" >
  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mantenerRegistro" name="mantenerRegistro" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SÍ ACEPTO" data-off="NO ACEPTO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
  <div id="console-event"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Ejemplo con jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mantenerRegistro').change(function() {
    $('#console-event').html(`Toggle:  ${this.checked}`)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="online center-block" >
  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mantenerRegistro" name="mantenerRegistro" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SÍ ACEPTO" data-off="NO ACEPTO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
  <div id="console-event"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: literal copiando el codigo que amablemente me han señalado en el desarrollo me pone este error: Uncaught TypeError: toggle is null
    <anonymous> http://localhost/sieca/avisoDePrivacidad.php:34  haciendo referencia a esta linea :  const toggle =  document.getElementById("mantenerRegistro");

Comment: con las lineas de jquery no me señala absolutamente nada. Estoy pensando que sea un error de librerias que esten dañadas. acabo de añadir la libreria en linea:<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  y nada simplemente no hace nada ....

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, ya obtuve un resultado de 4,  cambie una librería de jquery, en el desarrollo que tengo no funciono la jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js , tampoco  jquery-3.4.1.js y ya por no dejar le cargue la jquery-3.5.1.js y si me aparece el Toggle: false o Toggle: true .   Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguien le es util de las dos funciones para ver que accion tiene el toggle, esta es la funcion que si esta mostrando el cambio `$(function() { $('#mantenerRegistro').change(function() { $('#console-event').html(`Toggle:  ${this.checked}`) }); });`

Tambien despues de que cambie la libreria jquery, ya funciona con el codigo original de la pagina: `$(function() { $('#mantenerRegistro').change(function() { $('#console-event1').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked')) }); });`

al colocar el "div" debajo del botón toggle coloca debajo de este 'Toggle:  ${this.checked}' cada que se hace clic cambia su estado entre "true" y "false".

Para el segundo div, solo agregue el numero 1 al evento de salida "$('#console-event1')" que es lo que imprime el "div",  en este momento para realizar las pruebas pertinentes se muestran dos "letreros" Toggle que cambiar a la par según el estatus del botón.

Saludos